# PHP file_get_contents & curl can get image files from some sites but not others. Why?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, get, file-get-contents

file_get_contents in PHP/Apache2 was getting user pictures from Facebook. It was working fine until recently.  Now, it always times out after a minute, with this error in my Apache2 error.log:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/999999999/picture?width=200): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Here is the code (I recently added $context to see if it made it work. It did not):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('https' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$fbprofileimage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=100',false,$context);
```

I tried curl and it doesn't work:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=100');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'StockBet');
$fbprofileimage = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

I found out that file_get_contents & curl will work with some sites, but not others.

The following works:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('https' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$fbprofileimage = file_get_contents('https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2017/08/03/104629909-GettyImages-630953738-bitcoin.240x160.jpg?v=1501760634',false,$context);

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2017/08/03/104629909-GettyImages-630953738-bitcoin.240x160.jpg?v=1501760634');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'StockBet');
$fbprofileimage = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

The above code can get the following image files as well:

- https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/SSGv_d2P6ymZVIq8Bm5IVqpcz6WZioCfbRh5rxMPcTc.jpg  (Reddit)
- https://try.alexa.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/alexa-logo.png
- https://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/fxxj3ttftm5ltcqnto1o4baovyl.png
  (eBay)
- [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/Gateway/Unrec/T2/Amazon_GW_DesktopShoveler_5_200x200.*CB503347722*.png](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/Gateway/Unrec/T2/Amazon_GW_DesktopShoveler_5_200x200._CB503347722_.png)
- https://bitcointalk.org/useravatars/avatar_7110.jpg
  https://try.alexa.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/alexa-logo.png

The above code cannot get the following image files:

- https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png
- https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/7rUl71NcpOwqZeJexHuZhA--/Zmk9c3RyaW07aD0xOTM7cHlvZmY9MDtxPTk1O3c9MjIwO3NtPTE7YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b24-/http://media.zenfs.com/en-US/homerun/aol_com_127/ce17fc9999cd894bf3a3dac1416b3230  (Yahoo)
- https://c.disquscdn.com/next/a0cd712/marketing/assets/img/brand/disqus-logo-blue.svg  (Disqus)
- https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/464794058229964800/uwlkErTI_bigger.png  (Twitter)
- https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/c0.31.284.149/p284x149/21337242_6083114387812_5783480223513182208_n.png?oh=3c78c007377ee96b844e91843dfdfddb&oe=5A183896
  (Facebook)
- https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/images/ca-en-watson-2-09112017-600x260-p1v1.jpg

Does anyone know why I can get image files from some sites but not others?

Comment: Have you tried logging the curl request using CURLOPT_VERBOSE? You can also use curl_getinfo prior to curl_close to see if any HTTP errors were reported.

Most likely those sites are blocking output if you are omitting a user agent or referer header.

Comment: @RubenVincenten Thanks for your response. I got it to work for my purpose.  See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 1):

For my purposes, which is to get user pictures from Facebook, I got it to work by using the following code:

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // need confirmed
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  // need confirmed.  I think this is key, as Facebook redirects to another URL and we need to follow
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");  // not needed confirmed
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);  // need confirmed
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1);  // need confirmed
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);  // not needed confirmed
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);  // not needed confirmed
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);  // not needed confirmed
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);  // need confirmed
        $fbprofileimage = curl_exec($ch);   
        if (curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        else {
          //$info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
         // Get the cookies:
          $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
          //$responseHeader= substr($fbprofileimage,0,$skip);
          $fbprofileimage= substr($fbprofileimage,$skip);    // need confirmed
          //echo "HEADER: $responseHeader\n";   // causes error
          //echo "\n\nINFO: $info\n\nDATA: $fbprofileimage";  // causes error
        }
```

I think what was key was this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

because when getting https://graph.facebook.com/999999999/picture?width=200 (where 999999999 is the user's ID), Facebook redirects to another URL.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);